# subprocess communicate function is always empty

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to print the output from a subprocess directly to a custom built terminal by using a custom print function. This involves two segments of code, the problematic one is here:

```
with subprocess.Popen(f"{command}", cwd=directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, text=True) as translator:
   self.terminal.printGUI("Starting print")
   while True:
      output, error = translator.communicate()
      if translator.poll() is not None:
         break
      if output:
         count += 1
         self.terminal.printGUI(output.strip())

   self.terminal.printGUI("Ending print")
```

where the print starts and ends with the subprocess, however, translator.communicate() is always empty. The custom print function being called is here:

```
def printGUI(self, text):
   self.textbox.configure(state="normal")
   self.textbox.insert("end", text + "\n")
   #delete first line if there are more than 100 lines
   if len(self.textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n")) > 100:
      self.textbox.delete("1.0", "2.0")
            
   self.textbox.configure(state="disabled")
```

this function works as expected, and is using a tkInter textbox.

The custom print function should be called as stdout receives text.

This segment of the program is expected to be a pipe from the stdout of the subprocess to a tkInter textbox, creating a terminal for a GUI. The subprocess being called takes a long time, and prints a lot to the terminal, so I am trying to make the printGUI print in live-time.

Comment: Are you sure the output goes to `stdout` not `stderr`? Also if the process terminates right after printing, your code will still break before processing it.

Comment: Note also that *communicate()* will block until the underlying subprocess terminates

Comment: @CtrlZ The expected behavior is that the printGUI function is called as the subprocess prints to the terminal. It is basically implementing the terminal inside a GUI. I dont think this is possible using run, do you know how i can grab stdout as it is being written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen(f"{command}", cwd=directory, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False, text=True)`

output of the program was being captured in stderr for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If your subprocess output is line-oriented then you can utilise this pattern:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from sys import stdout

COMMAND = "/bin/ls" # <-- your command goes here

with Popen(COMMAND, stdout=PIPE, encoding="utf-8") as p:
    if p.stdout:
        while line := p.stdout.readline():
            stdout.write(line)
```